# How can I add formatter in only [tooltips] at noUISlider tag?

Tags: angular, tooltip, nouislider

I'm trying to add tooltips with the format. but it only works with below code

```
tooltips: [ true, true ]
```

but it won't work when I use my code like below

```
tooltips: {
  format: { to: this.toFormat, from: Number }
}
```

and

```
format: { to: this.toFormat, from: Number }
```

How can I add format only in tooltips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a formatter as one of the values in the array you are passing to `tooltips`:

```
tooltips: [ { to: this.toFormat, from: Number }, true ]
```

The relevant documentation is [here](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-tooltips).